# Override JPA of IBM WAS

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, websphere

I am using JPA 2.1 in my project (Hibernate 5.x) and deploying in IBM WAS 8.5.5.

Since IBM WAS 8.5.5 supports only JPA 2.0 by the container, There is persistence loader issue during application deployment.

Is it possible to configure custom JPA at app level in WAS.

I already tried - [IBM WAS Documentation](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/can-i-use-jpa-2-1-on-websphere-application-server/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With class loading strategy, I was able to override the JPA 2.0 of container.

using the inputs from [IBM Developers support](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/238952/websphere-application-server-v855-support-jpa21-fo/).

Answer (score 0):

You said you tried https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/can-i-use-jpa-2-1-on-websphere-application-server/, but what part of this document is not working? This is the page I would reference if you are trying to get JPA 2.1 running on 8.5.5.

Some alternate suggestions:

1. Traditional WebSphere v9 supports the JPA 2.1 specification level. I would recommend using WebSphere v9 for your project instead of 8.5.5 if you really need to use Hibernate 5.x
2. Hibernate 4.2 was the last version that supports JPA 2.0. You can downgrade to this version of Hibernate if you dont have to use JPA 2.1

Either of these solutions gain you container support and will provide the JPA API bundle for you. Whichever you go with, make sure not to bundle your Hibernate JPA persistence API bundles in your application. Hibernate repackages its API into "hibernate-jpa-2.x-api.Final.jar". I have seen this before as a conflict that customers build into their applications.